# Background images not appearing on some android devices using phone gap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I had developed the application using phone gap and tested in android devices. In few devices my background image is not loading properly.

Please advice on is there any html tag not supported in few android devices and in web view ?

Here's screenshot image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue happens because of the different browser syntax. So added background-image and background:url for the background. Here's the sample and it's fixed in all devices.

```
background: url(&quot;img/layer2.jpg&quot;) repeat scroll 50% 0px / cover  transparent;
background-image: url(&quot;img/layer2.jpg&quot;);"
```